# Example of non-principal ideal of the quotient ring $R[x,y,z]/(xyz-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Suppose $R$ is an integral domain, $R[x,y,z]$ is polynomial ring over $R$, and $$Q=R[x,y,z]/(xyz-1)$$
is a quotient ring. How to prove, that $Q$ is not principal ideal ring?
I was trying to compose an ideal that cannot be generated by one element, but fruitless yet.

**Edit:** I guess this fact could be proven without constructing non-principal ideal, but I'm mostly interested in a proof in which such construction is made.

Comment: I suggest to try first $R$ a field and $I=(x-1,y-1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $Q \simeq R[x,y]_{xy}$. Now try finding a non-principal ideal in $Q$, while recalling how ideals arise in localisations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What does the lower index $xy$ mean in $R[x,y]_{xy}$?

Comment: Um, that means the localisation of $R[x,y]$ at $xy$. I take it that you've not seen localisations yet ?

Comment: I didn't see this notatioon before, it was like $S^{-1}R$

Comment: Oh, in this case $S=(1,xy,x^2y^2...)$.In any case, think about an ideal in $R[x,y,z]$, a simple looking one, such that any element belonging to that ideal vanishes at (1,1,1). Can you find one ?

Comment: A simple looking ideal in $R[x,y,z]$, you mean $(xyz-1)$?

Comment: No, something like $(x-a,y-b,z-c)$, where you have to choose $a,b,c$ accordingly so that it contains $(xyz-1)$.

Comment: @user26857, for a domain $R$ I could give a proof. For a general ring more work is required I think.

Comment: If $R$ is a domain then we can immediately assume that $R$ is a field, and this is what I suggested the OP to try. (But, in fact, the field case solves the general question, since we may mod out by a maximal ideal of $R$.)

Comment: @user26857, I don't understand, how do we jump from $R$ being a domain to $R$ being a field?

Comment: @SoumyaSinha, I added the condition that $R$ is an integral domain, could you please add details to your answer?

Comment: @Glinka The field case is enough. Did you solve it? (If $R$ is an integral domain just  consider the ring of fractions of your ring with respect to the multiplicative set $S=R\setminus\{0\}$.)

Comment: @user26857, no, I didn't, sadly. I don't understand yet why $I=(x-1,y-1)$ is not principal, but $J=(x,y)$ is. I mean. I understand hypothetically how this should work, but I don't know how to find such $a$ that $(x,y)=(a)$. Also, it's a mystery for me how to prove that there's no such $b$, that $(x-1,y-1)=(b)$.

Comment: @Glinka In $Q$ the elements $x,y,z$ are invertible, so $(x,y)=Q$.

Comment: @Glinka, suppose you have $(x-1,y-1)=(a)$. Then the defining relation of localisation tells you that exist $f,g \in R[X,Y]$ such that $af=X^nY^n(X-1), ~ag=X^mY^m(Y-1)$, for some $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, can you find a contradiction? BTW since as user26857 rightly points out, you can assume $R$ to be a field, then dimension theory easily concludes everything.